# Unable to run app on Nexus 6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My app is working perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S4, but when I try to run it on Motorola Nexus 6 , I get runtime exception.

I have recently changed build variants: presentation:devDebug, data:debug

gradleVersion '2.14.1'

```
12-01 20:52:37.357 1808-1808/? E/ctxmgr: [PlaceFenceHelper]NearbyBuffer is null!
12-01 20:52:37.770 846-6904/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
     12-01 20:26:07.847 21100-21107/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
    12-01 20:26:08.694 21100-21100/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.dev.debug, PID: 21100
                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/spongycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;
                                                           at com.q42.qlassified.Provider.QlassifiedCrypto.encrypt(QlassifiedCrypto.java:31)
                                                           at com.q42.qlassified.Provider.QlassifiedKeyStore.encrypt(QlassifiedKeyStore.java:177)
                                                           at com.q42.qlassified.Provider.QlassifiedKeyStore.encryptEntry(QlassifiedKeyStore.java:119)
                                                           at com.q42.qlassified.QlassifiedFactory.put(QlassifiedFactory.java:70)
                                                           at com.q42.qlassified.Qlassified.put(Qlassified.java:120)
                                                           at com..presenter.utils.QlassifiedHelper.generateEncryptionKey(QlassifiedHelper.java:38)
                                                           at com.presenter.BaseApplication.initMainRealmConfiguration(BaseApplication.java:32)
                                                           at com.presenter.AndroidApplication.onCreate(AndroidApplication.java:24)
```

Comment: Is `com.presenter.AndroidApplication` package name of your app? Have you included `spongycastle` dependency ? Are you using `Bouncy Castle` ?

Comment: Have you included BouncyCastle in your gradle build?

Comment: I did not want to present full app name beacuse of copyrights, I will check it out but I think problem is about build variants @VaradChemburkar

Comment: Well, it says `NoClassDefFoundError` for `BouncyCastleProvider`. So have you included it in your gradle build?

Comment: @VaradChemburkar It is not there, but why i do not have problems on other devices?thx

Comment: It's hard to comment without knowing your project structure. Are you including JAR to libs folder? or are you adding  dependencies in `build.gradle` ? Can you recompile and install again on Samsung Galaxy 4 and then check? Does including dependency in `build.gradle` solve your problem?

Comment: post your `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` please

Answer (score 0):

> I think you have to check the runtime permission if your device has marshmellow OS.